# How to make gem install command only install when not installed or update needed

Tags: ruby, rubygems

i've read the documentation from rubygems site, but i guess the "gem install" command always reinstall, recompile everything, even if the same version already installed..

how to make gem install command only install when needed?

Comment: This doesn't directly answer your question, but Bundler would solve this for you and provides dependency management: http://gembundler.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to use something external like [gembundler](http://gembundler.com/) to handle project’s gem installation.

If you must use rubygems directly for this, a command like

```
ruby -e "puts `gem install GEMTOINSTALL` if(`gem list --no-versions | grep GEMTOINSTALL`) == ''"
```

would do the job.

Answer (score 29):

It looks like the `--conservative` flag will make the gem command do what you want.

```
gem install rake --conservative
```

From the documentation `gem install --help`:

> --conservative Don't attempt to upgrade gems already meeting version requirement

Answer (score 1):

That is why we use `bundle install`. This command will look into the `gemfile` for the gems.

This Gemfile says a few things. First, it says that bundler should look for gems declared in the Gemfile at http://rubygems.org. You can declare multiple Rubygems sources, and bundler will look for gems in the order you declared the sources.

Bundler will connect to `rubygems.org` (and any other sources that you declared), and find a list of all of the required gems that meet the requirements you specified. Because all of the gems in your `Gemfile` have dependencies of their own (and some of those have their own dependencies), running `bundle install` on the `Gemfile` will install quite a few gems.

If any of the needed gems are already installed, **`Bundler` will use them**. After installing any needed gems to your system, bundler writes a **snapshot** of all of the gems and versions that it installed to `Gemfile.lock`.

When you run `bundle install`, bundler will (by default), install your gems to your **system repository of gems**. This means that they will show up in `gem list`. Additionally, if you are developing a number of applications, you will not need to download and install gems in common for each application. This is nice for development, but somewhat problematic for deployment.

**In a deployment scenario**, the Unix user you deploy with may not have access to install gems to a system location. Even if the user does (or you use sudo), the user that boots the application may not have access to them.

As a result, bundler comes with a `--deployment` flag that encapsulates the best practices for using bundler in a deployment environment.

The `--deployment` flag requires an up-to-date `Gemfile.lock` to ensure that the testing you have done (in development and staging) actually reflects the code you put into `production`. You can run `bundle check` before deploying your application to make sure that your `Gemfile.lock` is up-to-date. Note that it will always be **up-to-date** if you have run `bundle install`, successfully booted your application (or run your tests) since the last time you changed your `Gemfile`.

Comment: You will still need to install/update bundler. Maybe using something like:

```gem install bundler --conservative```